# Why the fourier spectra concentrated to the border of the image (in Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, fft

I am confusing about a question related to fourier transform.
In matlab, I created an image:

F = [ zeros(56, 128); ones(16, 128); zeros(56, 128)];

which was an image as follow:
[image]

Then I transformed it with:

Fhat = fft2(F);

and tried to show the fourier spectra:

imshow(log(1+abs(Fhat)),[]);

The image was like follow:[image]

I wondering why the fourier spectra I got was concentrated to the border of the image?

Is there any mathematical interpretation?

I am new in this area, so please explain for me in detail if possible!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `fftshift` is the function to avoid that problem.

Comment: I know the fftshift method, but I just want to know what make the fourier spectra concentrated to the border.

Comment: Your image just has very low frequency components in one axis, so that's what the FFT shows.

Comment: It seems right, isnt it? You should have the frequency of X axis and frequency of Y axis and then the combination of them. However, the frequanzy in X axis is 0 for the whole image, therefore you only have vaues in the freq of Y without X. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform

Comment: How can I know the F are vaues in the freq of Y, not the X ?

Comment: This blog post might be of interest to you: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/09/22/fourier-transforms-vertical-lines-and-horizontal-lines/?s_tid=Blog_Steve_Category

Answer (score 1):

Unlike you might expect matlab places the low frequency components on the edge of the image.

In terms of frequency the fft values will go [+low f -> +high f -> -high f -> -low f]. I don't know why matlab does it like this.

As @Kamtal commented you can use [fftshift](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) to rearrange the fft matrix so that the zero frequency component is at the center.

Given this knowledge the transform you achieved is as expected. There is no change in the x direction in your input image so only the lowest x frequency components have non-zero values, and these are at the edge of the image.

Comment: It's not that Matlab does it like this. It follows from the _definition_ of FFT: start from low frequency up to high frequency; and when you get to the middle frequency (Nyquist rate) you see the lower part of the next replica of the original spectrum, centered at the sampling frequency

Comment: @LuisMendo ahhh, interesting. That makes sense.